# text box event on accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have a textbox over accordion header , now if i type space into the textbox my accordion get collapsed if it is open. so prevent that i have written following code

```
  $(".edit").click(function(event) {

// if default text is present then select the whole content
  if ($(this).attr('default') == $(this).val()) 
         this.select(); 
        event.stopPropagation();

 });
```

Now the problem is when i dobule click then whole content written inside textbox is not selected (Which is a default functionality of a textbox)

so to over come i have written following code

```
$(".edit").dblclick(function(event) {
    this.select();
 });
```

but now again if i double click then whole text is getting selected but if i single click then the text inside textbox remain selected only it doesn't behave normally.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this question might be a tad old, but you could be using the HTML5 `placeholder=` attribute to mimic this behavior natively in the browser.

Alternative solutions:

- Don't use placeholders, use a `<label>` instead.
- Use a **[ready pleaceholder alternative](http://www.hagenburger.net/BLOG/HTML5-Input-Placeholder-Fix-With-jQuery.html)**.

HTML5 `placeholder=` attribute already has a decent support on all major browsers. You can use the alternative script to enhance it using something like **[Modernizr](http://modernizr.com)**